# Ubuntu is stuck on the loading phase when connecting an online account

Tags: internet, ubuntu-gnome, online-accounts, webkit

Whenever I attempt to add Google as an online account through the settings, it gets stuck with `Loading "accounts.google.com"` in the bottom-left corner of the window that appears. This behaviour seems to be the same for any services that require the loading of web content to add the account, such as Facebook.

If I leave the loading screen going for 5 minutes, it eventually comes up with a Google login prompt, however entering my details there leads to another wait followed by a message saying "Sorry, something went wrong there. Please try again." from Google.

**EDIT:**

This seems to have been reported before, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1550727. The link indicates that this is a bug in WebKit.

**EDIT2:**

I have managed to bypass this issue: it seems to have a problem with the network which I am using to add the account. I am connected to my network via ethernet cable, so to experiment disconnected the cable and connected to the network via Wi-Fi, producing the same issue. When I launch a hotspot on my phone, however, and attempt to add the account whilst connected to that, I am able to successfully connect.

Comment: This seems very similar to [this very recent question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1087791/616451).

Comment: Haha, how interesting: same question within 10 minutes of each other.

Comment: Also a local network issue for me, but I am also struggling to push to ssh remotes (BitBucket etc.) using ipV6 so I think this could come down to bad network configuration