# Online accounts are very slow

Tags: online-accounts

I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu and I really like it, but I have some issues with Online Accounts. When I'm trying to add the Google Account, the app is **really slow**. Eventually, the google page to login shows up(after about 2 minutes), but immediately after I enter the email and click connect, I get an error: "Cannot connect". What I'm doing wrong?

Please notice that I'm a beginner in the Linux world so if it's possible to guide me, I'll be very grateful. Thanks for your time.

EDIT: Based on [this response](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087793/ubuntu-is-stuck-on-the-loading-phase-when-connecting-an-online-account) I was able to fix the problem by connecting to a phone hotspot.

Comment: Hi Ion, can you either answer your own question, then, or close this one since it's resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this response](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087793/ubuntu-is-stuck-on-the-loading-phase-when-connecting-an-online-account) I was able to fix the problem by connecting to a phone hotspot. It seems that the problem is related somehow to the network. Previously I tried multiple wi-fi networks, but it didn't work.